# iOS: opening image from photolibrary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm calling a view (that contains just an ImageView) passing the picture's path from library's user. And then, on *viewdidload* I'm loading the image. But, the image is getting a "super zoom" on the upper right corner of the picture, I don't know why!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

    UIImage *picture = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: self.picturePath];
    UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:picture];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

}
```

Comment: What are the dimensions of the photo? Try logging the frame of the imageView: `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(imageView.frame));`

Comment: Returned {{0, 0}, {3264, 2448}}

Comment: I already tried:     self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height); before addSubview...Get the same result

Comment: If you have an outlet for a `UIImageView` (called self.imageView) then there's no need to create another in your `viewDidLoad` method. You're creating a new image view and adding it on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, the image you are loading is very large. The `UIImageView` that you're creating is taking on the width/height of the image. You can either set the frame of imageView, or use and `IBOutlet` from your nib to add the photo to an existing `UIImageView`.

In your code you're creating a new `UIImageView`, so your updated code would look like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

    UIImage *picture = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: self.picturePath];
    UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:picture];
    // Set your frame size
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 320.0);
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

}
```

Comment: Of course! This works :) thanks Corey! Now, the picture it's small...There is anyway to I set this image to use all screen? Like native photo library of iPhone...

Comment: imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height);
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill; for full size picture!